# Loops in Assembly Language

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

Suppose A={1,2,3,4} and B={2,3,4,5} be two arrays. How can we initialize them by using loops? And how can we add corresponding elements of these arrays and store them into 3rd array by using loops? My assembler is masm615.

```
include irvine32.inc

.data

word ayyay1 5 dup(?)

word ayyay2 5 dup(?)

.code

main proc

top:

----------

----------

loop top

call dumpregs

exit 

main endp   

end main
```

Comment: Add the code you've tried to develop so we can get a feel for how much you know.

Comment: You don't need to use loops as you know the values that need to be in the array. Why not just initialize ayyay1 and ayyay2 with what you have?

Comment: Yeah, I know that we can initialize them without using loops, but I'm asking for my own knowledge that "How can we use loops to initialize two arrays as well as add their corresponding elements".

Answer (score 0):

Untested but generally guiding:

```
include irvine32.inc

.data

word ayyay1 5 dup(?)
word ayyay2 5 dup(?)

.code

main proc

  lea  edi, [ayyay1]
  lea  esi, [ayyay2]
  mov  ax, 1
  mov  bx, 2
  mov  cx, 4

top:
    mov word [edi],ax
    mov word [esi],bx
    inc ax 
    inc bx
    add edi,2  ; add to point to next word location
    add esi,2  ; add to point to next word location
loop top

call dumpregs

exit

main endp

end main
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your time. but It is giving many errors. Please help me with error-less code.

Comment: `esi` and `edi` would need to be incremented by 2. Also, it seems a bit overkill to have 3 counters when 1 would do.

Comment: @Micheal, I stated it was general pseudo code and given that the OP seems to be a beginner I wasn't going to introduce address offsets in the mov. I will fix the error though, thanks!

Comment: Sir, it is giving many syntax errors.
line 5(missing operator),
6(missing operator),
12(undefined symbol),
13(undefined symbol),19(Syntax error),20(Syntax error).

Comment: @Knowledge32: this is clearly home.  You've been handed the answer on a silver platter modulo some hiccups.  You get to do your share.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer it is not homework. If you don't know the answer then do not reply.

Comment: Rest assured, I know the answer.